# Remove specific value inside string

Tags: javascript

What I'm doing I'm trying to remove the quotation in array in Java
this is the code

```
Array [ "johan|39012|manager|2010", "" ]
```

What I wanna or what I aspect

```
"johan|39012|manager|2010"
```

Comment: please show what you've done to try and solve this yourself - by the way, you aren't removing "quotations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and you will have an array with of good string:

```js
const arr = [ "johan|39012|manager|2010", "" ];

const newArr = arr.filter(item => item.length > 0);

console.log(newArr);
```